# show image background 1 if div is on the left and show background 2 if image is on the right?

Tags: php, css

hi i wonder if anyone can help, not entirely sure this is possible but i have a div container called `<div class="scroll">`

inside div scroll is a sql query that echoes comments posted by users from the database. the div scroll is set to a width of 600px and so the comments will be arranged in this div left to right, theres two comment boxes on each line, each comment box is just under 300px each as to align next to each other.

the comments are listed like so:

```
<div class="scroll">

comment 1 | comment 2
comment 3 | comment 4
comment 5 | comment 6
</div>
```

the comments are encased in the div "comment_box"

now what i have done is put a background image to the div "comment_box" this image is a pointer arrow that points to the left and is positioned on the left hand side of the div, but i also want to have a second background image for the comment boxes that align on the right, so in this instance comments 2, 4 and 6 will have a different background image/an arrow that points to the right on the right hand side of the div.

is this possible?

thanks

```
comment box{

.wall_post_case_branch {
    background-image:url(../img/effects/arrow_left.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    height:90px;
    width:290px;
    position:relative;
        border:#ccc 1px solid;


}

mysql:

<?php
    if(mysql_num_rows($wallposts_set) > 0) {
        while ($posts = mysql_fetch_array($wallposts_set)) {
            $age = days_from_date($posts['date_added']);
            ?>
            <div class="comment_box">
             <?php echo "{$posts['content']}"; ?>
             </div>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with mysql?

Comment: you can add new `class` for `odd` or `even` record and give style accordingly.

Comment: it may be possible to sequence or categories the comments so that certain ones appear left and others appear right in conjunction with css this would make it possible to add a second background image to a secondary div element

Comment: @DipeshParmar could u please give me an example of how i might do this thanks

Comment: @BearJohn see my answer for that

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as below.

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    while ($posts = mysql_fetch_array($wallposts_set))
    {
        $class = ' odd';
        if ($i++ % 2 == 0)
        {
            $class = ' even';
        }
        echo '<div class="comment_box'.$class.'">';
    }
?>
```

and in `css`

```
.odd { background-image:imageone.jpg; }
.even{ background-image:imagesecond.jpg; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would right before the while loop make the variable `$i = 0;`.

It would use that to define what background color it should use.

Then in the while loop I would use this code:

```
while ($posts = mysql_fetch_array($wallposts_set)) {
    $i++;
    $age = days_from_date($posts['date_added']);
    echo "<div class=\"comment_box_$i\">
    $posts['content']}
    </div>";
    if ($i == 2)
        $i = 0;
}
```

Then the boxes will have 2 difference classes, the one of the left will have the `class="comment_box_1"` while the right box will have `class="comment_box_2"`.

Then you can create your CSS for the difference boxes.

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this simply with CSS by using:

```
:nth-child(even)
:nth-child(odd)
```

The fiddle illustrates with background colors instead of images.

http://jsfiddle.net/ingvi/CFMcA/

hope it helps